# Jquery - Top or the bottom of the page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've seen some new examples of ASP.NET that have scripts rendering at the bottom of the page but not sure  what is best. Should I render all my scripts at the bottom of each page where required or go with the usual  way?

Cheers

Comment: Bottom. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784616/mvc-4-where-to-load-js-scripts/14784665#14784665

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

So you should always put your script at the bottom of your page if possible to speed up your website as well as improve your SEO, website score and ranking.

> When a user requests a page from your site, the page HTML starts
>   streaming to the browser. As soon as a browser encounters a tag for an
>   external image, script, CSS file, etc., it will start downloading that
>   file simultaneously.
>
> If you put your scripts at the bottom of a page, they'll be loaded
>   last. In other words, the HTML content/structure/css/images of youe
>   page/app will be loaded first, and something can show up in the
>   browser faster; Your users don't have to wait for a script to finish
>   downloading before they see something in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should render your scripts at the bottom (right before closing  tag). http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Make sure that you keep the right order though - jQuery first. Also, if you put an inline script that uses jQuery anywhere before the call to it, it won't work.