# ASP.NET MVC: JavaScript not affecting HTML in Master page if its order in the page comes after @RenderBody

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

In ASP.NET MVC, JavaScripts included after a @RenderBody() do not seem to affect the @RenderBody() content. It must be placed before. i.e.

Master Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

</head>
<body>

    @RenderBody()
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Derived Page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Settings";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Master.cshtml";
}

<div id="status">Status</div>

<script>
    $("#status").hide().fadeIn();
</script>
```

For the derived page, at the time of the hide().fadeIn() call, it will not have loaded jQuery yet, so the browser logs show a JavaScript error.

However, if I place the jQuery include `<script>` tag before the @RenderBody(), the jQuery gets loaded fine.

I am wondering why it must be before in order to work? I would like to put it after, since it is better to place script tags at the bottom of the HTML file for better performance.

Comment: You are including jquery AFTER you are trying to use it.  Makes complete sense that the script inside your view won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything runs top-to-bottom in the rendered HTML. It's not pre-compiled in advance the way a compiled language is.

So in order to use jQuery, you must first have the jQuery source script tag. That's why it's generally accepted to but script tags for libraries in the head instead of the body. Then you can use jQuery (or whatever library you're using) anywhere in the body.

Comment: When your entire page relies on jQuery it is probably okay to make sure it loads at the top as you've said about libraries!

Comment: No, it's not generally accepted to put script tags in the head. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784616/mvc-4-where-to-load-js-scripts/14784665#14784665

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Well, everyone says to do that, but most people don't actually do it - if you look at the source of StackOverflow itself, as well as the Yahoo page you reference in your answer, the one that says to put scripts at the bottom, you'll see some scripts at the top. That's why I say "generally accepted" - whether or not it's the best idea or not, people do it all the time, and it does make life a lot easier.